# Filtering a collection in a rails API endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have two API endpoints of the form below.

```
GET api/v2/products/brands/<brand>/, 
GET api/v2/products/brands/<brand>/<category>/
```

I have two tables in my database: products (which includes brand and category_id columns) and categories.

The idea is if I do a `GET api/v2/products/brands/<brand>/`, I get all categories matching a specific brand string.

If I do `GET api/v2/products/brands/<brand>/<category>/`, I get a list of products matching specific brand and category strings.

How do I implement this in my routes.rb?

Comment: `GET '/api/v2/products/brands/:brand' => 'brands#show'`, `GET '/api/v2/products/brands/:brand/:category' => 'brands#show_category'`. You're going to have to be more specific with your question for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @meagar . This is what I needed, apologies for the late reply (timezone issues) and for my question not being specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @meagar above, these are the route specifications that I needed in routes.rb:

```
get '/api/v2/products/brands/:brand' => 'brands#show'
get '/api/v2/products/brands/:brand/:category' => 'brands#show_category'
```